# weighted least absolute regression in python?

Tags: python, regression

I was wondering if there's a function in Python that can find the best-fitted line (in 2D) or best-fitted plane (in 3D) of a set of data by **least absolute deviation** and while considering **uncertainties of the points**.

In fact, I have 3d points, which I want the best-fit plane of them. There is Weighted least square (WLS) fit function in both sklearn and statsmodel python libraries, and by putting q=0.5 in quantile regression of statsmodel I get the least absolute deviation. However, how can I have **Weighted Least Absolute regression** fit function?

Answer (score 0):

Least-squares, or equivalently chi^2-based, methods are easier because their first derivative is a smooth function. If you want absolute deviation to be minimized then you can use [`scipy.minimize()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html) with appropriately defined objective function. The other approach is to find ranges on which your objective function is smooth, optimize each range in a linear fashion, and then choose optimal value among these results.

Comment: And if I want the uncertainties of the points to be effected in the minimization, what to do?

Comment: Multiply absolute differences by `1/uncer.` or `1/uncer^2` - it's your choice.